# I am trying to make a program but i dont know what im doing wrong

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program that asks the user a file input with the prompt "New file name" and the program should work like this and if the name has any form and/or combinations of "importantdocument.text" and i try the new forms and how can i make the code work easier than keep putting `{variable} != {form of importantdocumant.txt}` can anyone help to see what i'm doing wrong or write a code that does what the program is supposed to do? thanks ahead of time.

my program

```
a = input('New file name: ')
if a != 'ImportantDocument.txt' and a != 'importantDOCUMENT.txt' and a != 'IMPORTANTDOCUMENT.TXT' and a != 'importantdocument.txt' and a != '':
    print('That name is allowed.')
elif a == 'ImportantDocument.txt' or a == 'importantDOCUMENT.txt' or a == 'IMPORTANTDOCUMENT.TXT' or a == 'importantdocument.txt':
    print('That file already exists.')
```

what the programs supposed to output

```
New file name: lessimportantdocument.txt
This name is allowed.
```

or

```
New file name: ImPorTaNtdoCumenT.tXt
That file already exists.
```

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking.

Comment: I don't know much about python, but i there has to be a `toupper` or `tolower` equivalent, checking for all combinations of CaPitalIZATION is unrealistic and prone to errors (like you have not checked ImPORtAnTDocuMENT.TxT as an example)

Comment: Please try to give a proper title like "Enter file name and check pattern" and be precise in you r writing as the lines before the code are very confuse.

Answer (score 0):

```
    a = input('New file name: ')
    k = a.upper()
    if k != 'IMPORTANTDOCUMENT.TXT':
           print("That name is allowed")
    if k == 'IMPORTANTDOCUMENT.TXT':
           print("That file already exists")
```

Comment: In Python 3.3+, you might use [`str.casefold`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) over `.upper()` or `.lower()` if you need to deal with Unicode issues like `'ß'` being lowercase and equivalent to `'ss'`, but not converted to `'ss'` on `.lower()` (though it goes the other way too; the dotless i `'ı'` is unchanged by both `.lower()` and `.casefold()`, but normalized to `'I'` by `.upper()`; non-ASCII is dumb).

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to check if the file exists, you could try read it. I've not tested this but it should work.

```
file_location = 'C:/Folder/' + a

try:
    with open(file_location , "r") as f:
        f.read()
except IOError:
    print("That file already exists")
else:
    print("That name is allowed")
```

If you literally just wanting to neaten up the code you have currently, then Mohd's answer is good.